# Writing $ e ^{3 z} $ in standard form.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I began by having: $z = x + iy$.

Making $e^{3z} = e^{3x + 3iy}$

I get stuck here. I'm supposed to write this function as $ w = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

Answer (score 3):

In Complex Analysis one defines for $z=a+bi\in\mathbb{C}$
$$
e^{z}:=e^{a}(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))
$$

Since 
$$3z=3a+3bi$$

you can set it in the definition.

Can you continue from here ?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $x^{a+b} = x^ax^b$. Use this and Euler's formula, $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $e^{3x}>0$, $e^{3iy} = \cos 3y + i \sin 3y$.